# Passing two arrays in a jQuery .post() , how do I catch this data in PHP and use it there?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm making a jQuery .post() with the following arrays:

```
'cleanedLinkStructureArray[]': cleanedLinkStructureArray,
'cleanedPermaLinkArray[]': cleanedPermaLinkArray
```

**The data inside these arrays:**
cleanedPermaLinkArray looks like this: ["2012","10","30","hello-world"]
and cleanedLinkStructureArray like this: ["year","monthnum","day","postname"]

**Javascript code:**

```
var ajaxPost = $.post(
            enableAJAX.ajaxurl, 
            { action: 'ajaxRequest',
            'ajaxRequestNonce' : enableAJAX.ajaxRequestNonce,
            'cleanedLinkStructureArray[]': cleanedLinkStructureArray,
            'cleanedPermaLinkArray[]': cleanedPermaLinkArray },
            'json'
    );

    ajaxPost.done(function(responseText) { 
        alert(responseText);
        console.log(responseText);
    }); 

    ajaxPost.fail(function() { 
        alert("Oops, I'm afraid we've broken something");
    });
```

I don't understand how I catch the two arrays in PHP? and use the data from the arrays inside PHP? Preferably I would create new PHP array with them, where the values inside cleanedLinkStructureArray become the keys for the array and the values inside cleanedPermaLinkArray the values for that new array.

I guess it must be something with this, but I need someone more experienced to tell me what I need to do here.

```
$_POST['cleanedPermaLinkArray[]']
$_POST['cleanedLinkStructureArray[]'];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Marnix

Comment: Do you mean "catch" or "cache"?

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays will be in

```
$_POST['cleanedPermaLinkArray']
$_POST['cleanedLinkStructureArray'];
```

you can do a simple `var_dump($_POST)` to see how the data is formed

Answer (score 1):

First, in $.post, you do not need the square brackets, so this is one of your params:

```
'cleanedLinkStructureArray': cleanedLinkStructureArray,
```

Then in PHP, you have to first catch it like such:

```
$cleanedLinkStructureArray = $_POST["cleanedLinkStructureArray"];
```

Now, you can use the following:

```
foreach ($cleanedLinkStructureArray as $item) {
    // Do something with $item
}
```

Another way is to pass all your params from $.post to php is setting them as json object.

Answer (score 0):

This is all coming down from the server as JSON, right?  Just use `json_decode` on the values and the'll be converted to arrays, natively inside of php.

```
$cleanedPermaLinkArray = json_decode($_POST['cleanedPermaLinkArray[]']);
echo cleanedPermaLinkArray[0]; // some value..
```

Comment: It comes back as JSON in the end yes, but before that I wish to create a new array. And that new array I will JSON_encode

Comment: And the data that is being sent to PHP is not in JSON I believe, the 'json' is just an indicator in the .post() request that it expects to receive a JSON string to be returned back

Comment: Are you saying you want to know how to create an empty array in PHP and pass it back to your Javascript in JSON?  $sJson = json_encode(array());